# Yii Framework how to hide index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

My `.htaccess` content is as bellow:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and url manager is as :

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlSuffix' => '.jsp',
        'caseSensitive' => false,
```

but when I access all sub pages and links except home page, without index.php it is not working.
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set main.php in your yii configuration, at component :

'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
 'caseSensitive'=>false,
```

),

if this is not work you can  add below script into urlManager array in main config file.

eg. -

```
'routeVar'=>'route'
```

Comment: Means I should remove `urlSuffix` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please modified your htaccess file with below code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And change protected/config/main.php [url manager block] with below code

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```